# Resultset is empty while executing trunc(sysdate) from Java/Jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am facing an issue with using the trunc(sysdate) from Oracle to run a query from jdbc.
I am able to connect to the database from the code and execute simple queries for testing purposes.
Below are the queries which i tried and and both seem to return nothing.

```
  //String sql ="SELECT CODE FROM TESTTABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(PROCESS_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') = (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL)";

    String sql ="SELECT PROCESS_DT,CODE FROM TESTTABLE WHERE  PROCESS_DT = TRUNC(SYSDATE)";

        //creating PreparedStatement object to execute query
        PreparedStatement preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();


        while(result.next()){
           String code = result.getString("CODE");
           System.out.println("---- code ----" + code);
        }
```

The query above does not return any rows from the database when run with jdbc code from java.
But the same runs in the PL/SQL developer and returns me the matched rows from the TestTable.

**Edit : Updated**

==============================

```
        PROCESS_DT , CODE

        11/21/2013    NFS

        11/22/2013    NFS

        03/10/2014    VPS
```

The datatype of PROCESS_DT is Date in the db and i want to compare it with current business/sysdate for my code.

Can anybody let me know what is the problem and am i doing anything wrong above and ways to correct it.
Any help will be great as i could not find much on the net for this issue.

Thanks
Vikeng21

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you want to run trunc on both ends of the date check.  Like this:

```
String sql ="SELECT CODE FROM TESTTABLE WHERE  TRUNC(PROCESS_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)";
```

Otherwise the query will only return when PROCESS_DT matches exactly with TRUNC(SYSDATE).  Another possibility is that your code is connecting to a different database than your sqldeveloper.

Comment: I have already tried the way you have suggested above and that didn't seem to work and i am connected to the correct db pretty sure as i did a select *  for the above query and i was able to get the resultset. any other ideas....

Comment: Can you add process_dt to the output and remove the where clause so that I can see what dates are in there?

Comment: Hi Zeki. Sorry could not reply yesterday as i was offline. I have updated my question above please have a look. here is the process_dt data. PROCESS_DATE ================== 11/21/2013 11/22/2013 03/10/2014 I changed my query today but need to find a solution for this problem as to what is the cause of this issue